# Python contains and icontains both return case insensitive results

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a very curious case that I'm not sure I understand.  I am filtering data using field__contains but am getting case insensitive results.  As an example:

Entry Data:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "last_login": null,
    "is_superuser": false,
    "username": "slappy",
    "first_name": "don",
    "last_name": "sweeney",
    "email": "don@bruins.com",
    "is_staff": false,
    "is_active": true,
    "date_joined": "2019-12-09T09:07:11.897502Z",
    "groups": [],
    "user_permissions": []
}
```

Search:

```
query = { 'email__contains' : 'DON' }
data_set = data_set.filter(Q(**query))
return data_set
```

The results return the entry despite the casing clearly being wrong.  I checked other filter types and they are working as expected:

Search 2:

```
query = { 'username__exact' : 'SLAPPY' }
data_set = data_set.filter(Q(**query))
return data_set
```

This search produces no results, as would be expected.

Am I missing something here?  Would could be the root cause of this?  I would expect contains to be case sensitive and icontains to be case insensitive, otherwise why would the two exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that information has been given with [**`documentation of contains`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains):

> SQLite users
>
> SQLite doesn’t support case-sensitive LIKE statements; contains acts
>   like icontains for SQLite. See the [database note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#sqlite-string-matching) for more information.

Comment: thanks for that, did not even think about sqlite in the back for some reason thanks